# How to remove certain email addresses from an array in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node Js application with the following array list,

```
['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']
```

and I want to remove all the `@gmail.com` email addresses from that array and get a new array like so.

```
['test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']
```

I've used the following method but I don't get the expected result I want

```
let ccemails =  filterItems('@gmail.com');
```

I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which return a new array with all elements which match a certain condition

```js
let arr = ['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']

var results = arr.filter(function(el){ 
    return !el.match(/.+\@gmail\.com/)
})

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) together for this:

```js
let arr = ['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']
// only items that don't end with gmail.com
let filtered = arr.filter(item => !item.toLowerCase().endsWith('gmail.com')) 

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array and check to see if each Item includes `@gmail.com` so for example

```js
let arr = ['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']

let ccemails = [];

arr.forEach((email) => {
    if(!(email.toLowerCase()).includes('@gmail.com')) {
       ccemails.push(email);
    }
}) 

console.log(ccemails);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [string.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
const arr = ['test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test@hotmail.com.com','test@yahoo.com']

const ccemails = [];
arr.forEach((email) => {if(!(email.endsWith('@gmail.com'))) {ccemails.push(email);}}) 
console.log(ccemails)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using .indexOf() for looking up gmail.com inside the mail address string. For example this code example prints the ones not including gmail.com as domain:

```
var mailAddresses = ['user1@hotmail.com','user2@gmail.com','user3@yahoo.com']

mailAddresses.forEach(function(mailAddress) {
    if(mailAddress.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf('@gmail.com') == -1) {
       console.log(mailAddress);
    }
});
```